# Hibernate - add condition to @ManyToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I have a question about hibernate @ManyToMany relationship. First, suppose I have `User` and `Position` with `ManyToMany` relationship. Here is `Position` collection in the `User`:

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_position", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "position_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
})
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("id ASC")
private Collection<Position> positionCollection;
```

I have used `@OrderBy("id ASC")`, so when I call `user.getPositionCollection()`, the result will be sort on `id`. Now my question is **how can I add condition to collection?** For example something like this:

```
@OrderBy("id ASC")
@Condition("id > 10")
private Collection<Position> positionCollection;
```

**Edit:**

I tested `@Where` annotation in this way(Note `deleted` is boolean):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
private Collection<Position> positionCollection;
```

This returns me an error **Unknown column 'positi0_.false' in 'where clause'**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that **false** is being recognized as a column name. 

Try `@Where(clause = "deleted = 'false'")`

Good luck!

Comment: This works for me with postgresql. But I'm not sure if this works for mysql and other driver without additional boolean support. In that case @mharray s answer might be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a config. But you can take a look at Hibernate [filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

the @Where annotation takes native SQL as a string, so assuming your boolean field is stored in your database as an int or bit, you would need to do `@Where(clause = "deleted = 0")`